# Calling a function every X seconds not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a thymeleaf template with this piece of code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  (function() {
    alert('lalala');
    // do some stuff
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
  })();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am expecting to see al alert in the page every second,] but nothing happens and I don't see any error in the console

Comment: Are you in strict mode? `arguments.callee` won't work if so.

Comment: Note that I added your code to an executable snippet where it appears to work fine (without `strict`), at least for me in Chrome. Also, I removed your references to ThymeLeaf as it's irrelevant to the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arguments.callee` is deprecated, if I recall correctly.

If you want to execute a piece of code every `x` milliseconds, this might suit you. Using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.

```
function repeatMe() {
  console.log("Lalala");
  //alert("Lalala");
}
var interval = setInterval(repeatMe, 1000);
repeatMe(); // To start it immediately

// Use this to stop the interval:
// clearInterval(interval);
```

If you really need to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, just call `setTimeout` again from the `repeatMe` function.